# Swift - decode only interested elements

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, jsondecoder

I have a huge json data obtained from HTTP response and I need only a particular portion to be decoded as a model.

```
{
    "root1": {
        "items": [
            {
                ...
            },
            {
                ...
            },
            {
                ...
            },
            {
                ...
            },
            {
                ...
            }
        ]
    },
    "root2": {
        ...
    },
    "page": {
        "size": 10,
        "totalElements": 5,
        "totalPages": 1,
        "number": 0
    }
}
```

This is my json template and I do not want to create model for root elements. I am interested only in the `items` array. Any direct way to decode it?

Comment: Turn the JSON string into JSON and then extract the items key as a model?

Comment: implement `init(from: Decoder)` manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select what to decode by using a `CodingKey` enum but you still need to decode from the top/root level.

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    let root1: Root1

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case root1
    }
}

struct Root1: Decodable {
    let items: [Item]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case items
    }
}
```

and then the decoding could be done as

```
var items: [Item] = []
do {
     items = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data).root1.items
} catch {

}
```

Comment: You don't need the manual `CodingKey` implementations here. That would only be applicable if the struct had more fields than keys it wanted to decode (in which case the coding keys would be a subset of the fields), or if they had different names than the key names

Comment: Yes I know. @ios you should select the other answer as accepted so I can remove this one

Answer (score 2):

When creating a `Decodable` type, you only have to declare the properties that you want to decode from JSON. All the keys that you don't care about can be omitted. You don't even need `CodingKeys` for this.

Think about the properties used for decoding as a minimum set of requirements, not as a complete set of requirements. Decoding will never fail because there are keys in the JSON that you didn't specify on your `Decodable` model.

You do need to decode from the top level through all intermediate levels though, so you have to declare top-level objects.

`Decodable` models:

```
struct Item: Decodable {
  ...
}

struct Root1: Decodable {
  let items: [Item]
}

struct Response: Decodable {
  let root1: Root1
}
```

Decoding:

```
let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: json)
let items = response.root1.items
```

Comment: I was thinking of the case when you have properties in your struct that isn't in the json. This is the better answer since it's less code.